# Can't figure out what this syntax error is

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm currently learning PHP through tutorials and I am trying to run the following code but getting an unexplained syntax error which no one else seems to be having occur with them.

**Error Message**
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ..../users.php on line 12

**Line 12 =**

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
```

**Full page Code**

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
function user_active($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`    = '$username' AND `active` =1"), 0) ==1) ? true : false;
}
function user_id_from_username ($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
function login ($username, $password) {
$user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

$username = sanitize($username);
$password = md5($password);

return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;


}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more closing round bracket.

```
                                                           /* v */
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("..."), 0, 'user_id')/* -> */)/* <- */;
                                                           /* ^ */
```

Comment: A comment would make sense

Comment: Thank you, that worked, it just didn't make sense to me on the tutorial I copied the code exactly and the lecturer had no such issues, thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for the attention getting comments

Comment: Look for a tutorial on [mysqli](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65) or [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: @user2542256, lecturer?

Comment: @zerkms I wasn't copy and pasting, I was watching a video while typing the code myself.

Answer (score 5):

you are missing a closing parentheses )
you have 3 opening but only 2 closing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function user_id_from_username ($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(
          mysql_query(
                "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"
           ), 0
    ), 'user_id');
}
```